# .rc to .o conversion in pre-build codeblocks, permission to access file denied

Tags: c++, winapi, codeblocks, pre-build-event

I am a newbie who has been trying to venture into some winapi coding with C++ in CodeBlocks.
I am struggling with adding an icon to the exe file. After creating .rc file and a header for it

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <commctrl.h>
#include <richedit.h>
#include "resource.h"

LANGUAGE 0, SUBLANG_NEUTRAL
IDI_ICON1          ICON           "C:\\Users\\Stanislaw\\Desktop\\WIN32api + other    Win development\\programujte.com_3_resource\\grafika"

resource.h header: 
#ifndef IDC_STATIC
#define IDC_STATIC (-1)
#endif

#define IDI_ICON1                               100
```

then the compiler requires .rc to .o conversion

and then using Cobeblocks Project/build options/prebuild:

```
windres 3_icon.rc 3_icon.o
```

It does not get past windres in the prebuild. I get the "Permission denied" saying that I cannot access the .ico file.

```
Running target pre-build steps
windres 3_icon.rc 3_icon.o
windres: can't open icon file `C:\Users\Stanislaw\Desktop\WIN32api + other Win   development\programujte.com_3_resource\grafika': Permission denied
```

I am using CodeBlocks 10.05 on Win Vista 32bit.

Comment: The reference to an `ICON` resource needs to specify the file - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381018(v=vs.85).aspx at a guess you're pointing to a directory?

Comment: If you wish to get extra rep, make it a standart answer and I will mark it as the right one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reference to an `ICON` resource [needs to specify a file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381018%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It looks like you're pointing at a directory instead of a file.

You will get `Permission Denied` error messages when trying to 'open a directory as a file'